# java runs fine with 'absolute' path, doesn't run with CLASSPATH specified

Tags: java

my program is in `package pl.edu.uj.tcs.crazySocket;` due to some requirements. I work in the crazySocket directory. In order to compile the program I use command

```
CLASSPATH=~/prog/colosseum/data javac tictactoe.java
```

and that succeeds. I want to run the program. I change javac to java and get rid of the '.java'. I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: tictactoe
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tictactoe
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
```

when I get up in the tree directory to the ~/prog/colosseum/data and run `java pl/edu/uj/tcs/crazySocket/tictactoe` all works fine.

What's wrong with the CLASSPATH? Shouldn't it work both with javac and java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your classpath, it's your call to `java` that's wrong.

You *need* to specify the full qualified class name `pl.edu.uj.tcs.crazySocket.tictactoe`.

Comment: you mean that I have to run the program from the base directory? I can't work solely in the crazySocket directory?

Comment: No, you can work from wherever you want. But you _always_ (regardless of where you are) need to pass the full qualified class name to `java`.